# ADB command history

Tags: android, adb

I need `ADB` command history similar to bash history.
I need a history file to be created in the Android phone.

Is there any such functionality?

If not, can any one point me to the code in `ADBD` where it receives the commands form the desktop?

I can implement the same.

I tried enabling shell history on Android, but it does not work for the commands invoked by `ADB`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code in ADBD to implement the functionality.
Modified file: system/core/adb/shell_service.cpp

```
bool Subprocess::ForkAndExec(std::string* error) {
    -----------
    /* Writing the command to history file just before it is executed. */
    addToHistory(command_.c_str());
    execle(_PATH_BSHELL, _PATH_BSHELL, "-c", command_.c_str(), nullptr, cenv.data());
    -----------
}

void addToHistory(const char * cmd)
{

        FILE *fp = fopen("/data/adb_history.txt", "a");

        if(NULL == fp)
        {
                printf("ERROR\n");
                return;
        }

        fwrite(cmd, strlen(cmd), 1, fp); 
        fwrite("\n", 1, 1, fp); 
        fclose(fp);
        return;
}
```

For now, it is working in superuser mode only.