# How to catch adb commands that send to android devices

Tags: android, adb

I am running a auto test tool on my PC with android devices connected;
I found that during the test, the tool send some adb commands to the device;
I want to know what the adb commands exactly is? How to catch the commands on PC or on the android device?

I want to get a result like:"adb install xxx.apk"

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/ this will help you.

Comment: To Anand: Thanks for your feedback; The link you provided is the introduction about how to install adb and use adb commands as I already know; What I want wo know is how to monitor the adb interface on PC or handset to catch the adb commands which send to android devices by Tools on PC.

Comment: You just want know commands which are run using `adb.exe`? Test tool may not be using `adb.exe` always to communicate to your device...For example-- If the test tool is installing some apk in your android device(if the apk has no activity u may not see in app menu) and the apk just listens for command in some port, From the PC the test tool will be writing to some commands/data local port. the test apk will interpret and act accordingly.. such commands will not directly using `adb.exe`. In this case you may need to sniff the USB using sniffers like wireshark and decode data being sent from PC.

Comment: which too are you using ? CTS ?

Answer (score 1):

You can trick the pc - script something in your favourite language and compile it to adb.exe.

The script would just tee the command into some file, and later you can read it. In order to do that, just rename adb.exe to something else, and when placing your fake adb.exe, just tee the command to some file and still call the adboldfile.exe.

It´s ugly and hacky but it will do the trick. Don´t know if there is a good way to achieve it.

If you are into recompiling adbd, you can also see this question and it´s response, it adds adbd commands to history:

[ADB command history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794872/adb-command-history)

Comment: Thanks, this inspired me to write my own adb and fastboot sniffer, even 5 years later. And it works not so bad. [ADB-and-Fastboot-Sniffer](https://github.com/newbit1/ADB-and-Fastboot-Sniffer)